# Intent returning null after leaving app and coming back

Tags: android, android-intent

If im staying in the app, this works fine

Click button to take me to new activity:

```
            intent.putExtra("invite_id", invite_id);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving Activity:

```
     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); //invite id is in here
```

Now here is the weird part. If I am in the app, then click home button to leave the app and go to the native contacts app and save ANYTHING (like edit a name or number...**the problem only occurs if I actually save something**), then go to recent apps and open up my app from there... now if I click the button to launch my intent to take me to a new activity, the receiving activity returns a null bundle

```
     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); //returns null
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Are you sure `invite_id` is not null before you send the intent?

Comment: Yes I checked using the debugger that invite_id is actually set. Then as soon as I pass it in the intent and receive it in onResume() of the receiving activity, it i all of a sudden not set anymore

Comment: What device / SDK are you on ? Do you reproduce the problem on other devices or simulators ?

Answer (score 0):

String b = getIntent().getStringExtra("invite_id");

Comment: getExtras() takes no arguments on my version of android studio

Comment: He is suggesting you call getStringExtra not getStringExtras but it wont solve the problem if the extras is null anyway

Answer (score 0):

Intent extras are always persisted across activity death and recreation. So, if you're stashing that extra value, it will continue to be there if you are resuming the app with the recent app switcher.

I would verify that you are stashing values in the intent.

Comment: What do you mean by "stashing values" in the intent??

Comment: Just that if you put values in to the intent extras, they will continue to be there. However, this all depends on you exiting and resuming the Activity in a certain way. If you hit the back button to back out of the activity, the extras are gone. If you swipe away the app in the app switcher, the extras are gone.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying now. To be clear, here are the sequence of events.

1.) open my app
2.) click home button
3.) go to contacts app
4.) save a new contact
5.) come back to my app from the app switcher and click a button to try to go to a different activity...I can see in the debugger that as I am creating the intent the extras I am adding are NOT null...but as soon as the new activity receives them, they become null....also weirdly enough, if I just go to the contacts page and don't save anything, then this issue does not occur

Answer (score -3):

simply that means that your `activity` being `recreated` so you have to options to avoid that:

1. Avoid `recreating` your `activity`  by setting this to your `Activity` within the `manifest`

> ```
> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"
> ```

2. Or by saving the instance of the `id` you received by doing such:

> ```
> @Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
>     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
>     outState.putString("myId",myId);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>         myId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myId");
>     }
> }
> ```